# How to link to libraries downloaded with Homebrew in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arm, cross-platform, gtkmm

I just downloaded [GTKMM](https://gtkmm.org) using Homebrew but I don't know how to link to it with Visual Studio Code. I have a c_cpp_properties file as well as a tasks.json (Both C/C++ settings files) that I can use to link to files with.

Do I link to the downloaded package directly (opt/Homebrew/Cellar/gtkmm) or do I need to link it to somewhere else, like /Library/Frameworks/?

I am on an ARM Mac, using C++ and Visual Studio Code. I also need to make sure my project is cross-platform.

Comment: If you're making anything non trivial especially if you want it to be cross platform, don't use visual studio code to manually invoke the compiler, use a cross platform build system like cmake or meson. There's an excellent cmske plugin for visual studio code which does all the building and intellisense configuration for you

Comment: Oh! I will look into that! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may install `pkg-config` and it will make the life of a developer sweeter:

```
brew install pkg-config
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm
```

The last command shows the required compiler and linker flags for using gtkmm.