# VS Code includePath issues with Homebrew installed packages for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, homebrew, include-path

Trying to learn C++ so I have to install libraries, however these being found by VScode.

I have installed some of them via Homebrew since that was the most simple way to get started because I've used Homebrew for Python before.

Now, when I try to run the following program (sample from mlpack)

```
#include<armadillo>
#include<mlpack>


using namespace mlpack;

int main()
{
  // Load the data from data.csv (hard-coded).  Use CLI for simple command-line
  // parameter handling.
  arma::mat data("0.339406815,0.843176636,0.472701471; \
                  0.212587646,0.351174901,0.81056695;  \
                  0.160147626,0.255047893,0.04072469;  \
                  0.564535197,0.943435462,0.597070812"); 
  data = data.t(); 

  // Use templates to specify that we want a NeighborSearch object which uses
  // the Manhattan distance.
  NeighborSearch<NearestNeighborSort, ManhattanDistance> nn(data);

  // Create the object we will store the nearest neighbors in.
  arma::Mat<size_t> neighbors;
  arma::mat distances; // We need to store the distance too.

  // Compute the neighbors.
  nn.Search(1, neighbors, distances);

  // Write each neighbor and distance using Log.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < neighbors.n_elem; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Nearest neighbor of point " << i << " is point "
        << neighbors[i] << " and the distance is " << distances[i] << "." << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This was just a copy and paste from the mlpack sample to see if I had installed everything correctly. However, as stated earlier, I get the fatal error that neither the mlpack nor the amrmadillo pack can be found. I have tried  different variants for the include line

`mlpack, mlpack.hpp, mlpack/core.hpp`

but these don't work either. I'm new to working with C++ and compiled languages so I suspect I'm missing some key information. From what I've gathered, the following will be important information if you would like to help.

VSCode: c_cpp_properties.json (I've manually put in the Homebrew directories that contain the packages )

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/opt/homebrew/lib/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/armadillo/12.6.1",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mlpack/4.2.0/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cereal/1.3.2/include",
                "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ensmallen/2.19.1/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-arm64",
            "compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

VSCode: tasks.json (tbh I only kind of understand what this does but I think this is find since the command matches up with my compiler path )

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-13 build active file",
            "command": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

an excerpt from my settings related to cpp

```
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "C_Cpp.default.enableConfigurationSquiggles": false,
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13"
}
```

I will also note that there are two compiler options which I am given the option to use

"/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13" - listed as my current compiler path
and
"/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc-13"

and it doesn't matter which one I choose. Nor does it matter if I use "clang", "clang++", "gcc" or "g++" (not installed with homebrew)

I also do not have a configurationProvider set. In another online form this seemed important - mine is default. Not sure if that means much in my case.

from what I can tell maybe I am missing something with Cmake or make tools. However, from my understanding homebrew should take care of this and/or this would only be necessary if I manually built the code from the source.

If you have resources I should look out for understanding this or any parts of this process I would appreciate that as well.

BTW - I am working with M1 Apple Silicon on Ventura 13.4.1. Although some may have deduced that from 'opt' in the homebrew path, apparently thats an apple silicon thing?

I tried the following:

1. changing the file name inside the include statement for different things like mlpack.hpp, mlpack/core, mlpack/core.hpp, etc. with different variants among them
2. adding to the VScode include path - before this the includePath was empty
3. changing the compiler path
4. All sorts of variations of the (1), (2), (3) - although the multiplicity of options is large so I have not tried every single combination
5. Restarting Computer
6. Full Quit VSCode
7. Many Google searches - this is where many of the (1), (2) , (3) changes were made

Read many of these post multiple times because I had to get context for the vocabulary. There were more that weren't related to my question. (1)https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8377

(2)https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/868

(3) [How to link to libraries downloaded with Homebrew in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776623/how-to-link-to-libraries-downloaded-with-homebrew-in-visual-studio-code)

(4) [VScode Mac "Cannot find /opt/homebrew"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778916/vscode-mac-cannot-find-opt-homebrew)
[vscode how to include leveldb installed on my Mac by HomeBrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716480/vscode-how-to-include-leveldb-installed-on-my-mac-by-homebrew)

(5) The following link seemed helpful but I didn't quite know what the responder was talking about
https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/102gbll/how_to_use_brew_installed_library_in_vs_code/

(6) This one was about python but somewhat useful
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/11p1m35/troubleshooting_path_issues_with_python_on_visual/

Comment: Trying to learn C++ does not mean you have to install libraries. As evidenced, you're not really learning C++. And beside all that, just let a package manager or cmake do it for you.

Comment: I should be clearer.  I've produced a lot of C++ files that just implement linked lists, merge sort, hash tables, and other basic algorithms. I'm aware of quite a bit of the syntax. But, I want to use C++ for some machine learning and scientific computing purposes, so I want to learn about the libraries that are advantageous (hence the mlpack and aramdillo includes) 

I really don't know enough about package managers and/or cmake to be able to solve this problem.  That's why I was using homebrew, at least I'm pretty sure. But it might be a C++, VScode, or a homebrew problem.

Comment: tasks.json controls how the project is built. And you don't include your include directories or library folders. Like I said, it's worth learning Conan or vcpkg (they're not difficult) and cmake. Let tools gather your resources and decide how to build your program. You worry about the code.